# Error in creating a hive table with avro serde

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

My colleague was getting an error while creating a Hive table with avro serde. Below is the code that he was trying and ended up with error.

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS twitter;
    CREATE TABLE twitter
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='{
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "twitter_schema",
    "namespace" : "com.miguno.avro",
    "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "username",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Name of the user account on Twitter.com"},
    {"name" : "tweet",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "The content of the user's Twitter message"},  
    {"name" : "timestamp",
     "type" : "long",
     "doc" : "Unix epoch time in seconds"}
     ],"doc:" : "A basic schema for storing Twitter messages"}');
```

I later found that an apostrophe "'" in line 17 was causing the issue.

```
"doc" : "The content of the user's Twitter message"},
```

In the above line the doc comment was included with a word that has an apostrophe. I removed it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you trying to ask a question here?

Comment: No, it is the issue I faced while creating the Hive Table. Just wanted to create an awareness.

Comment: @AlexRaj, you should add an answer to your own question, instead of answering the question in the question field. :)